# How to connect to HTTPS through proxy using urllib2 (in Python)

Tags: python-2.7, http, https, proxy, urllib2

If the website I'm trying to connect to via a proxy is unsecured (HTTP), then I'm able to connect, however if it's secured (HTTPS), then I can't.

The following code works:

```
import urllib2

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com').read()
```

However the code below does not work,

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https':'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

html = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.example.com').read()
```

Instead I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html:

> Changed in version 2.7.9: cafile, capath, cadefault, and context were added.

This one allowed me to connect to my local HTTPS site that is using a self-signed SSL certificate:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com'),\
context=ssl._https_verify_certificates(False)
```

I noticed in your traceback the similarities with mine. The code, just like you posted, works on Ubuntu 14.04 (Python 2.7.6) but not in 16.04 (Python 2.7.13) with exception to the last one:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

I'm not sure if this work on your end.